# Heroku not reflecting codes pushed to it and differs from Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, localhost

I have done up a web app with Ruby on Rails and made some changes on my codes in my computer. Thereafter, I did git add ., git commit, git push and git push heroku master.

The Localhost:3000 webpage reflected the codes and showed the change but on heroku, the webpage did not reflect the codes/change.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you add more details?

Are you pushing to the correct heroku bucket?

Try clearing your cache, try heroku restart. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you precompile? Otherwise you won't see css changes.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Also see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline